# How can I change the content without looping using keyframe animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Any idea on how to change the text without looping? I don't want to use the `infinite` in animation.

```css
.text {
  animation: changeText 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes changeText {
  0% {
    content: '';
  }
  50% {
    content: 'First Paragraph';
  }
  100% {
    content: 'Second Paragraph';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Change me</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove parameter `infinite` from `animation: changeText 5s infinite`. And also, if you dynamically change text using css, then you need to use pseudo-class `:before` or `:after`. Like that:

```
.text:before {
  content: '';
  animation: changeText 5s;
}
```

Here's a simple example.

```css
.text:before {
  content: '';
  animation: changeText 5s;
}

@keyframes changeText {
  50% {
    content: 'First Paragraph';
  }
  100% {
    content: 'Second Paragraph' ;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text"></div>
```